# Execute TestNG.xml from Jenkins (Maven Project)

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, jenkins, testng

1. My Project dosnt have a bin folder
2. Have tried the following:

> D:>java -cp "Pathtolibfolder\lib*;Pathtobinfolder\bin"
>   org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Any Ideas?

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski thanks for the prompt response, it says it cant locate the bin directory, my project is a maven project so dosnt have a bin folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Maven then i would simply use the surefire plugin and run tests as part of the build:

```
<plugins>

    ...

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    ...

</plugins>
```

Just specify the path to your testng.xml and take advantage of it if you can use this kind of configuration.
It allows for tons of parametrization and i have used it extensively in my projects.

Check out this tutorial to get a hang of it: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html

Comment: @Phil_P85 if the answer provided by Maciej worked, please help accept his answer.